# how to sum json array value

Tags: ios, swift

How to sum values from json array I am getting:

```json
[
  {
    "quiz_id":"1",
    "user_id":"193",
    "quiz_question_id":"1",
    "question":"Sample Quiz",
    "answer_id":"2",
    "quiz_user_marks":"4",
    "final_answers":"Question 3"
  },
  {
    "quiz_id":"1",
    "user_id":"193",
    "quiz_question_id":"2",
    "question":"Another Sample Quiz",
    "answer_id":"2,3",
    "quiz_user_marks":"-1.33",
    "final_answers":"Question 3,Question 4"
  }
]
```

and I retrieve json value like

```
array = json.arrayValue.map{$0["quiz_user_marks"].doublevalue}
```

I want to sum this array value how to do it

Comment: You need to decode it first into an array of objects (are you familiar with [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)?), and then simply sum up the resulting array. It's unclear which part (decoding into an array or summing up an array) you're having difficulties with.

Comment: i dont know how to do it.i'm new to this help me if you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you *might* be using SwiftyJSON right now, but it's not clear from the question. I'm going to use `Codable`, as suggested in the comments.

```
let data = """
                [
                  {
                    "quiz_id":"1",
                    "user_id":"193",
                    "quiz_question_id":"1",
                    "question":"Sample Quiz",
                    "answer_id":"2",
                    "quiz_user_marks":"4",
                    "final_answers":"Question 3"
                  },
                  {
                    "quiz_id":"1",
                    "user_id":"193",
                    "quiz_question_id":"2",
                    "question":"Another Sample Quiz",
                    "answer_id":"2,3",
                    "quiz_user_marks":"-1.33",
                    "final_answers":"Question 3,Question 4"
                  }
                ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

One issue is that right now, all of the dictionary values are marked as `String` in your JSON (ie, quoted) -- that's a little unfortunate, as you won't get convenient conversions to their real types right out of the box. But, you can still do the conversions later on. I'm going to keep as much automatic Codable work as possible, but you may want to implement your own `Decodable` `init` to deal with this (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

```
struct Quiz: Codable {
    let quizID, userID, quizQuestionID, question: String
    let answerID, quizUserMarks, finalAnswers: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case quizID = "quiz_id"
        case userID = "user_id"
        case quizQuestionID = "quiz_question_id"
        case question
        case answerID = "answer_id"
        case quizUserMarks = "quiz_user_marks"
        case finalAnswers = "final_answers"
    }
}
```

```
do {
  let quizArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quiz].self, from: data)
  let userMarksSum = quizArray.compactMap { Double($0.quizUserMarks) }.reduce(0,+)
  print(userMarksSum)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

I'm using `compactMap` because the conversion from `String` to `Double` could fail.

---

If your current code is working already (my suspicion is that there's at least a typo on `doublevalue` which should probably be `doubleValue`?) you may be able to just use the `reduce` line from my solution:

```
let answer = json.arrayValue.map{ $0["quiz_user_marks"].doubleValue }.reduce(0,+)
```

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase for further simplifying the decoding.